# Matching 2 numbers Regex PHP excluding one combination

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code:

```
preg_match('/^COD([0-9][1-9]|0)$/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

And I want to match CODXX, where XX can go from 01 to 99.

This way  is matching all, except COD10
COD20 and so on...

If I use

```
preg_match('/^COD([0-9][0-9]|0)$/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

This way is matchig all, including COD00, which is not allowed...

Any solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the `|0`, are you trying to permit a match for `COD0`? (just exclude `COD00`?)

Comment: COD0 is not allowed. It shoudn’t match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the leading 0 values separately in your regex so as to exclude `COD00`:

```
preg_match('/^COD(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

If you *want* to match `COD0`, leave the `|0` in the regex:

```
preg_match('/^COD(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|0)$/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

Comment: Thanks! For me the first approach is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Just negative lookahead for `00`, then repeat two digits:

```
/^COD(?:(?!00)[0-9]{2}|0)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/wHL9Wg/1

This allows `COD0`, though - if that's not desirable, then the pattern shouldn't include the `|0` alternation:

```
/^COD(?!00)[0-9]{2}$/
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformace! Good approach !